# What is the current U.S. monetary standard?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, economy

Despite my greatest efforts, I could not find any information about what standard the U.S. is using at this time. Apparently, we used to be on a gold standard. What about now? Do we even have a standard?

Comment: Define "monetary standard".

Comment: Care to define "value"?  Marx has a sustained definition.  I'm not aware of any other definition that's sustained in that way.  (Kudos to the marginalists who decided to elide the problem of value and research their own issues btw.)

Comment: @Chantola What do you mean by "value"? You see the problem here? You are operating on a set of mistaken assumptions about money. Money is just whatever a person will take.

Comment: @TylerDurden I would imagine value as being whatever price the market wants to pay for a item. That would be it's value. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Chantola When you say "pay" for an item, what do you mean? Pay dollars? So, you are saying the "value" of a dollar is how many dollars someone will pay for a dollar? Also, how is a market price a "standard"?

Comment: @TylerDurden by pay I mean pay in whatever other commerce someone wants to give for the item.

Comment: @Chantola Then it's not a payment is it, because you "pay" money, not goods? This whole question is about economics, not history. The purpose of the forum is not to be a lecture on Econ 101. If you are interested in these matters I suggest reading the "Wealth of Nations" by Adam Smith, or if that is too long a book for you, read "Of Money" by David Hume.

Comment: Not a history question at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The American dollar is now [*Fiat Money*, unbacked by any physical asset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_United_States_dollar#Fiat_standard)

Comment: Except the Fiat in my driveway? :)

Comment: @CGCampbell: Ah! Is that also "unbacked by any physical asset"?

Comment: The instruments of the US government would seem to be "assets" in some definition, and the latent threat of force of US arms backs that fiat.  Needs more theoretical consideration.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: I have considered it from time to time, and am leaning to the premise that the underlying asset to *fiat money* is possibly the ability to pay one's taxes with it; particularly one's income tax.

Comment: Without wishing to expand a discussion, you might enjoy Dave Graeber's _Debt_ about the role of "states" (repressive class apparatus) in forcing monetary relations in the long duration.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: I undoubtedly would - remind me again in ten years or so once I have retired.

Comment: @CGCampbell yes, and just as prone to rusting

Comment: It may be more accurate, and add a historical element, to add its role as the world's reserve currency and the agreement for this at Bretton Woods

Answer (score 28):

The United States abandoned the [gold standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretton_Woods_system) on 15 August 1971. Since then it has been using [fiat money](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money), which is not backed by any commodity. It derives its value solely from government authority.

This is sometimes also known as a "managed currency standard".

Comment: It's a stretch to say the dollar "derives its value *solely* from government authority". That's the foundation for sure, but its value floats freely on international currency markets.

Comment: @BrianZ Not really, just a difference in perspective. You're talking about the dollar's precise *monetary worth* (in terms of other currencies); I meant value as in the *property* of being valuable/desirable in the first place.

Comment: @BrianZ and the US government can and does directly influence that by buying up dollars on the market, or by adding more dollars to the market.

Comment: @Semaphore I appreciate that distinction. But the authority of the state does not apply directly to international markets, where the dollar does have value. There the value rests more on the production of the US economy (and institutional factors which cannot be reduced to state authority, like the denomination of oil prices in US dollars). But this gets into the chartalist vs monetarist debate that has been around forever.

Comment: @jwenting Yes, that the state uses its power to "directly influence" the value of its currency is beyond a doubt. But the distinction between "directly influence" and "solely determine" is not irrelevant.

Comment: So anyway, replace "solely" with "primarily" in the original answer and I think it is clearly correct.

Comment: @BrianZ You clearly don't appreciate that the word "value" has different meanings, because your comment simply restates your previous one and ignores the distinction I just pointed out. This is not only a discussion, but also one that goes around in circles. Neither is suited for the comments.

Comment: Sadly not from government, government is a user of currency, the value, interest rates, debt and quantity are highly regulated by central banks which banks are not directly under governments.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary Okay, but none of that has anything to do with my answer. The point is that fiat money has value solely because a government has declared it legal tender. Central banks (which are still government institutions) are irrelevant to that.

Comment: @Semaphore you are right, it is not neccessarily related to the answer. I just wanted to point out that central banks are typically independent or semi-independent from the government. Which is a mistake in your answer otherwise it is basicly the core of an answer for the question.

Comment: @Semaphore The gold standard never had very much to do with "giving money value" in the simplistic sense you define. The dollar was legal tender long before the gold standard was removed, and that's first and foremost what made it desirable to most users who accepted it. Everyday users of the dollar never thought very much about trading paper in to the government for gold, except when they were making a populist political point. The primary function of the gold standard was historically very much about regulating what you are calling the monetary worth of the currency.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to answer it even if briefly it is already answered by Semaphore and Pieter Geerkens

The money itself not backed by any physical assets, to understand the current situation, the existing two answers contain the "Fiat money" definition, which is one big part of the story.

The complete story is way bigger than it can be told in this single answer, but I will try to collect all vital, and useful information since I was interested in it for few years now.

First of all, an official source: [Modern Money Mechanics](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Modern_Money_Mechanics) from Federal Reserve central bank (mostly privately owned bank), which tells us how money is created out of nothing (actually from some demand of money supply), which means unlike previous money system backed by gold or silver assets (or anything limiting factor) the money supply can be expanded theoretically to infinity (see [Hyperinflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation)), but in reality people lose faith in currency by that time and start bartering.

I would recommend lectures from documentaries like: [Money Masters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1954955/), or Chris Martenson's and Albert Bartlett's lectures available on youtube (the scope of theirs are broader than just money system). Also might be useful Mike Maloney's "Hidden Secrets Of Money", which contains a good part of monetary history.

I wouldn't recommend Zeitgeist movie even if it contains valuable informations, it is sort of manipulative and you might get drifted far from the information which you are looking for.

For summary: the standard of USD technically the faith of the people (not just US citizens, but foreigners too), which is losing rapidly in the past 10 years, for ex China started agreeing not using USD for international trades so far with 8 currencies (most recently EUR), and also there are serious debates on how to trade oil without using USD.

Comment: +1 Because the "summary" makes a *very* good point: that the **monetary standard of the US is essentially *public faith***. However the rest of the post is rather problematic in all sorts of ways, and reads more like a discussion on fiat money than an answer to the question.

Comment: @Semaphore I would recommend the first source for reading primarly since the others are somewhat opinion based, but all of them help to see clearly in the question. I thought on linking them to the answer but since **this monetary related part** is pretty much factual, I decided to mention them, it might be easier to understand than a dry book.